# How to fix Segmentation fault while accessing shared library function in C programming?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, shared-libraries

i created a shared library file named Library.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int Addition(int a, int b)
{
    int s;
    s = a + b;
    return s;
}
```

debug the share library

```
gcc -shared -o libshared.so Library.c
```

create a small program that access the shared library function

```
#include<stdio.h>
int Addition(int a, int b);
void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int total;
    total = Addition(19, 23);
    printf("Total = %d\n", total);
}
```

debug the program

```
gcc -o foo foo.c -L. -shared
```

execute the program and i get the error

```
Segmentation fault
```

using gdb i got the current output

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007fffffffe4ca in ?? ()
#2  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Comment: Did you mean `-lshared` in the second gcc command?

Comment: Try `cp libshared.so /usr/lib/`. You might like https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22926/where-do-executables-look-for-shared-objects-at-runtime

Comment: I copied the library file as you said. But it didn't work. so i export the library file like this `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/` then i checked `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to see if it is set. But the Segmentation fault persist

Comment: @TomekSzpakowicz No I didn’t. But as soon as did that it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 2nd gcc command:

```
gcc -o foo foo.c -L. -shared
```

you have `-shared` instead of `-lshared`. So instead of linking to `libshared.so` you build `foo` as a shared library. For some reason on your system trying to execute a shared library causes a segfault instead of producing a more meaningful error message.